# Excel VBA - Expand range from using just one column to using multiple

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working piece of code that looks at a columns value, copies those values, and strips off the 'speed' component string of that value - Turning '200 Mbps' into just '200', etc.

They updated the source data on me and the values are now in three columns - AC, AD, AE instead of just AC now.  So values can exist in either column and any row, can be Gbps and Mbps, etc.

At the end of the day, I need the total of the three columns and X number of rows.  I have sample data below.

How can I (or can I even) modify this existing code to account for the extra two columns.  I am wondering if the Dictionary approach is correct at this point.  It was originally added at someone else's suggestion.

```
Dim Cla As Range


With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each Cla In wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("AC9", Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        Cla.Value = Replace(Cla.Value, " Mbps", "")
        Cla.Value = Replace(Cla.Value, " Gbps", "")

        If Not .exists(Cla.Value) Then
        .Add Cla.Value, Nothing
        End If
    Next Cla

     wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D13").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.keys)
    End With
```

I don't really understand the `If` and `With` loops and how they combine with `keys` and `Transpose` like this. ((Thanks TinMan for the info))

I've tried moving this out, but having this outside the loop breaks the code.  Is there something in this section that I need to update?

```
 If Not .exists(Cla.Value) Then
                .Add Cla.Value, Nothing
                End If
            Next Cla
```

Some sample data looks like this:  Notice each element is on its own row.

```
AC  AD  AE
300     

        123

72      


    200 



        101
```

The 300 gets paste where it belongs but nothing else adds up or get grabbed I think.  Also, when the data looks like THIS, it pastes two values instead of just one: 
Notice the 300 and 123 are now on the same line, 300 gets paste into the destination cell and 123 gets paste into two cells below that.

```
AC  AD  AE
300     123

72      


    200 


        101
```

Comment: Edited down my original post in an attempt to be more clear.

Comment: You should add a screenshot of original data and one of expected output.  I still don't know what you are actually trying to accomplish.  I think that original data was processed correctly but you want all the numbers gathered into a single column on a different worksheet but I am not sure.

Comment: Not gathered into a single column - but a single Cell, a summation cell.  So the source data is in multiple columns and multiple rows, but the output data will be inserted to only a single cell (D12).  I mentioned I was having a problem with it pasting two different values into two cells, versus the sum of those values into a single  cell.

Comment: If all that you are doing is summing & keeping count of the values then why are you using a dictionary?  Do you realize that the whole `If Not .exists(Cla.Value) Then` part will ignore ALL duplicate values?  Is this actually what you want? It doesn't sound like it.

Comment: can you please add a screenshot of how the input looks like? it's way easier to understand the image vs your description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you are describing the problem correctly.  Clearly, using the dictionary, get you a list of unique distinct values.  But you stated that:

> At the end of the day, I need the total of the three columns and X
>   number of rows.

The existing code leads me to believe that you are going to be doing a count of different speeds...how many 200 Mbps, how many 72 Mpbs, etc.

***Either that, or the previous code didn't work as intended.***

Assuming that you described the problem correctly and all you want is the total bandwidth then this should do the trick...

```
Dim LastRow As Long, Value As Long, Sum As Long, Count As Long

' Get the last row, looking at all 3 columns "AC:AE"
LastRow = FindLastRow(wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("AC:AE"))

' Iterate through all 3 columns
For Each Cla In wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("AC9:AE" & LastRow)

    ' Use Val() to get just the numeric value and the inline IIF() statment to automatically adjust the speed
    Value = Val(Cla.Value) * IIf(InStr(Cla.Value, "Gbps") > 0, 1000, 1)

    ' Check if there is a Value, if so, Add it to the Sum (and increment the count)
    If Value > 0 Then
        Sum = Sum + Value
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
Next Cla

' Write the Sum to the other Workbook (not sure if you need the Count)
wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D13") = Sum
```

And a function to find the last cell in a range (even if the list is filtered)

```
Public Function FindLastRow(r As Range) As Long
' Works on Filtered Lists/Hidden rows
Const NotFoundResult As Long = 1 ' If all cells are empty (no value, no formula), this value is returned
    FindLastRow = r.Worksheet.Evaluate("IFERROR(LARGE(ROW('" & r.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & r.Address & ")*--(NOT(ISBLANK('" & r.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & r.Address & "))),1)," & NotFoundResult & ")")
End Function
```

Comment: This looks to be a good solution @Profex !!  Thank you and everyone else for their repeated posts, attention and time!  Also appreciate the commenting of the code, helps me learn better.

Answer (score 2):

### Example 1

Use `Range.Resize()` to extend the number of columns targeted.

```
For Each Cla In wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("AC9", wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)

Next
```

### Example 2

Set a helper variable to the Range and use `Range.Resize()` to extend the number of columns targeted.

```
Dim Target As Range
With wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0")
    Set Target = .Sheets("Sheet0").Range("AC9", .Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)
    Debug.Print Target.Address
End With
```

### Addendum

This will strip away the " Mbps" and " Gbps" as well as insert the sum the a;; the numbers into `Range("D13")`.

```
With wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0")
    Set Target = .Range("AC9", .Range("AC" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3)


    For Each Cla In Target

        Cla.Value = Replace(Cla.Value, " Mbps", "")
        Cla.Value = Replace(Cla.Value, " Gbps", "")

    Next Cla

    .Range("D13").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Target)

End With
```

Comment: This suggestion seems to be closer to a solution but not quiet right.  It is copying AC, AD, AE, but only in one row, not looping through and adding all the values together in all three columns.  It is also pasting in D13 and D15 now for some reason instead of just D13.

Comment: The ` Debug.Print Target.Address` does show the correct range that I am reading from, but the same output issue persists.  The numbers in the three columns / multiple rows are not being added together it seems, just 'pasted' into the destination cell.

Comment: I have added sample data to my OP to highlight what I am seeing when I paste.

Comment: `Dictionary.Keys()` is a 1D zero based array of unique values.  `Application.Transpose(.keys)` transposes the `.Keys` array to a 1 column 2D array.  If you are trying to get a list of all the values in the range then add the values as items to the Dictionary and uses the `.Items()` array to retrieve them.

Comment: It also seems strange that you are making not converting the numbers to common units.  Why would you want `300 Mbps` to equal `300 Gbps`?

Comment: We don't want the Mbps to Equal the Gbps, we are stripping off the "bps" string and adding the values that exist within.  I have another check that converts 1 Gbps to 1000 Mbps, so the math ends up working correctly in the end.

Comment: Doesn't this already 'add' the values it finds in the columns?  `           If Not .exists(Cla.Value) Then
            .Add Cla.Value, Nothing
            End If`

Comment: It adds the values as a  key and nothing as the values.  Keys are unique values.

Comment: There are a lot of examples here: [VBA for Smarties - Dictionary](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on your question I gather that you want the sum of the original inputs that are contained in columns AC, AD and AE. Such sum you want to store it at cell d13. Since I have limited input, this is the least ugly code I can provide:

```
nRow1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "AC").End(xlUp).Row
nRow2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row
nRow3 = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Row
nRow = Application.Max(nRow1, nRow2, nRow3)
input_range = Range("AC9:AE" & nRow)
acum = 0
For Each cell In input_range
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
       temp = Split(cell, " ")
       acum = acum + CInt(temp(0))
    End If
Next
Range("D13").Value = acum
```

Comment: You are correct:  "you want the sum of the original inputs that are contained in columns AC, AD and AE [of wbFrom in Sheet 0]. Such sum you want to store it at cell d13 [in wbTo in Sheet 1]."  I am trying to implement your example but am getting a error:  `"91 Object variable or with block variable not set"`' but I have assigned all of the nrow1/x to `Dim nrow1 to Ranges`

Comment: my guess is that you're using Option Explicit for your code. If you are doing that then to create a range you need to change 'input_range = Range(...)' for 'set input_range = Range("AC9:...")'